# How do I use Name as an applicative?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scalaz, applicative

```
scala> val a = Need(20)
a: scalaz.Name[Int] = scalaz.Name$$anon$2@173f990

scala> val b = Need(3)
b: scalaz.Name[Int] = scalaz.Name$$anon$2@35201f

scala> for(a0 <- a; b0 <- b) yield a0 + b0
res90: scalaz.Name[Int] = scalaz.Name$$anon$2@16f7209

scala> (a |@| b)
res91: scalaz.ApplicativeBuilder[scalaz.Name,Int,Int] = scalaz.ApplicativeBuilde
r@11219ec

scala> (a |@| b) { _ + _ }
<console>:19: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method FunctorBindApply in class ApplyLow of type [Z[_]](implicit t: scala
z.Functor[Z], implicit b: scalaz.Bind[Z])scalaz.Apply[Z]
 and value nameMonad in object Name of type => scalaz.Monad[scalaz.Name]
 match expected type scalaz.Apply[scalaz.Name]
       (a |@| b) { _ + _ }
                 ^
```

`Name` is an `Monad`, therefore an `Applicative` too. Why doesn't this code work then? Do I need to put any type annotations to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a partial answer, I'm not too familiar with scalaz. `(a |@| b)` is an `ApplicativeBuilder[Name, Int, Int]`. Your call to `apply(plus: (Int, Int) => Int)` requires two implicit parameter, a `Functor[Name]` and an `Apply[Name]` (a little less than `Applicative`, there is no pure).

There is a problem with the second one. As `Name` appears in type `Apply[Name]`, companion `object Name` is considered for  implicit scope, and so the implicit `val nameMonad: Monad[Name]` is in the implicit scope. As `Monad` extends `Applicative` which extends `Apply`, it is a possible candidate for the implicit parameter.

But as `Apply` appears in `Apply[Name]` its companion object `Apply`, companion `object Apply` is considered too. And in its ancestor `ApplyLow`, there is an

```
implicit def FunctorBindApply[Z[_]](implicit t: Functor[Z], b: Bind[Z]): Apply[Z]
```

Instances of `Functor[Name]` and `Bind[Name]` are present in implicit scope (nameMonad is both of them), so `FunctorBindApply` provides a candidate `Apply` too (which would behave exactly as nameMonad as it is completely based on it, but it is another candidate nevertheless).

I don't think I really understand the priority rules. Having definition in `ApplyLow` rather than `Apply` would reduce the priority relative to something defined in companion object `Apply`. But not relative to something defined in unrelated object `Name`. I don't think `Monad` being a subtype of `Apply` counts as making it more specific. And I see no other rule that could decide between the two, but I must confess I'm a little at loss there. The compiler error messages certainly agree it can choose between the alternatives.

Not sure what the right solution should be, but having `nameMonad` directly in scope, for instance with `import Name._`  should give it priority.

Comment: We haven't found a reasonable solution to give us the right implicit priorities when relying on the implicit scope. Importing the type classes instances explicitly is sometimes the only way. New designs are being prototyped for Scalaz7 (http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/wiki/Scalaz7) to avoid this problem.